# Java set add to put a custom add impl

Tags: java, set

I need to be using an implementation of `Set` interface for storing objects of type `MyObject`.

`MyObject` has two fields: `id` and `score`. For equality on `MyObject`, only `id` is used. One of the functionality I need to use is to be able to support to be able to add `score`s when two `MyObject`s (with same `id`s) are inserted into this set.

Currently, I am using `TreeSet` and its isn't working the way I want it to work.

```
    Set<MyObject> container = new TreeSet<MyObject>();
    MyObject obj1 = new MyObject(12, 0.345);
    container.add(obj1);

    MyObject obj2 = new MyObject(12, 0.1);
    container.add(obj2);
```

I want container to have `Myobject(12,0.445)` but it being a set, the container has `MyObject(12, 0.1)`.

Is there something I can use which will give me what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Map` for this:

```
Map<Integer, Double> container = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>();
```

or

```
Map<Integer, MyObject> container = new TreeMap<Integer, MyObject>();
```

Then you can call `get` on the container to see if the object is already there, and increment its score.

A `Set` will not work for you because there is no efficient way of getting the `obj1` from the Set.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code/classes to follow the below semantics

```
if(container.contains(newObj))
{
  MyObject oriiginalObj = container.get(newObj);
  originalObj.incrementScore(newObj.getScore());
}
```

There are other ways of doing this like extending the TreeSet and overriding the add() method or by delegation (suggest using [Guava's forwarding collection](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingCollection.html)) but the solution I provided is simple and explicit.

Correction: Use TreeMap instead of TreeSet as suggested by Thomas

Answer (score 0):

The add method for the TreeSet implementation looks like this

```
private transient SortedMap<E,Object> m; // The backing Map
public boolean add(E o) {
return m.put(o, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

where PRESENT is a dummy object used to indicate the object added already exists.
you could subclass TreeSet to use the score sum instead of a dummy object

or, if possible, get rid of the Set altogether and instead use directly the Map as @Thomas says